# Разметка в rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте! Имеется партиал с таким кодом:

```
<div class="row">
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<div class="col-md-3 nopadding">
<div id="<%= post.id %>" class="postid">
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
            <%= link_to post.user.name, post.user %>
            <% if current_user?(post.user) %>
                <%= link_to "X", post, method: :delete,
                                         data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
                                         title: post.content,
                                         class: 'close' %>
            <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
  <%= image_tag post.image.url(:medium), :class => 'img-thumbnail' if post.image.file? %>
    <span class="content"><%= post.content %></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

в итоге html код выглядит примерно так:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 nopadding">
 пост 1
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 nopadding">
 пост 2
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 nopadding">
 пост 3
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 nopadding">
 пост 4
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 nopadding">
 пост 5
</div>
</div>
```

а мне нужно, что бы html код выглядел так:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="post">
                   пост 1
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                    пост 5
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="post">
                   пост 2
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                    пост 6
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="post">
                    пост 3
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                    пост 7
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="post">
                    пост 4
                </div>
                <div class="post">
                    пост 8
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

подскажите как можно такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
<% @posts.each_slice(2) do |posts| %>
     <div class="col-md-3">
          <%= posts.each do |post| %>
              <div class="post">
                   .............
              <div/>
          <% end %>
     <div/>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @DarkSun, получилось, но он вставляет две строки из базы данных после каждых двух постов, просто, в не блока, выглядит так: [#<Post id: 331, content: "", user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-03-05 12:18:19", updated_at: "2014-03-05 12:18:19", image_file_name: "", image_content_type: "", image_file_size: , image_updated_at: "2014-03-05 12:18:13">, #<Post id: 328, content: "", user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-03-05 12:11:36", updated_at: "2014-03-05 12:11:36", image_file_name: "", image_content_type: "", image_file_size: , image_updated_at: "2014-03-05 12:11:30">]